# Mongodb select some fields from DBRef

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I am building an application using Spring 4.1, Spring data mongodb 1.7.2 and MOngodb 3.0. I have the below document structure. I would like to select some of the fields from retailer not all the fields like products while querying answer. How to achieve that?

I tried below code but it didn't work

```
public List<Answer> findAnswerByLastModifiedAndCreatedBy(Date createDate,String createdBy){

        Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("lastModifiedDate").gte(createDate).and("answerText").exists(true).ne("").and("createdBy").is(createdBy));

        query.fields().include("answerText").include("id").include("retailer.$shopName").include("retailer.$id");

        List<Answer> answers = mongoTemplate.find(query, Answer.class);
        return answers;
    }

@Document(collection="answer")
@TypeAlias("answer")
public class Answer extends CommonDomainAttributes implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4195056255932348897L;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public Answer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    Question question;

    @DBRef
    @Indexed(background=true,name="ANSWER_RETAILER",dropDups=true)
    private Retailer retailer;

    @TextIndexed()
    @Indexed(background=true,name="ANSWER_ANSWRTEXT",dropDups=true)
    private String answerText;
 }

 @Document(collection="retailer")
@TypeAlias("retailer")
public class Retailer extends CommonDomainAttributes implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2712025356211775960L;

    public Retailer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @DBRef
    @Indexed(background=true,name="RETAILER_USER",dropDups=true)
    private IdeaRealtyUser user;

    @DBRef(lazy=true)
    private List<Product> products;

    private String shopName;
}
```

Comment: I have tried BasicQuery query = new BasicQuery("{ 'lastModifiedDate' : { '$gte' : { '$date' : '2014-12-31T18:53:35.092Z'}} , 'createdBy' : '9886310626' , 'answerText' : { '$exists' : true , '$ne' : ''}}"," { 'id' : 1 , 'answerText' : 1,'retailer.$id' : 1 }"); But this also not working.

Comment: But Query returns data as expected db.answer.find({"_id" : ObjectId("561cc992e4b0697465ea9548")}, { "id" : 1 , "answerText" : 1,"retailer.$id" : 1}).pretty();
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("561cc992e4b0697465ea9548"),
 "answerText" : "",
 "retailer" : {
  "$id" : ObjectId("561a999277c84fe0d87380fd")
 }
}

Comment: Ai'm still facing the same problem:( Anybody knows the answer?